# play rewind and stop button on UINavigationController

Tags: iphone

Requirement of my app is to have `UINavigationController` at the bottom with play, rewind and stop buttons on it. Play button will play audio and will have multiple `ViewControllers`. what should be the code to display `UINavigationController` at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UINavigationController` should generally go at the top of the view (as per the H.I.G.).

A bar at the bottom should be a `UIToolbar` where you create your own buttons (`UIBarButtonItem`) and give them to the toolbar.
`UIBarButtonItem` has default items for Play, Stop, and Rewind (and many others)

If you already use a navigation controller, you can show its default toolbar (setToolbarHidden:NO) and create/set the items in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

UINavigationController is a container that maintains a stack of UIViewControllers and a NavigationBar. You could try using the UINavigationBar separate, but you'd likely be better off just making some custom graphics on an imageView at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Got it with the frame definition display it at the bottom like

```
MyCustomNavigationBar *navigationBar = [[MyCustomNavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 435, 320, 25)];
```